# Why is my string of type `bytes`?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

According to *Real World OCaml*, the type of `"abc"` should be `string`. But actually in my `utop` REPL, it's of type `bytes`.

I've already opened `Core.Std`. Why is that?

(The version of `OCaml` is `4.02.2`; `Core` is `112.24.01`; `utop` is `1.18`.)

Answer (score 14):

You must enable safe string mode explicitly. Just start utop with:

```
$ utop -safe-string
```

Before [the introduction of](http://blog.camlcity.org/blog/bytes1.html) type `bytes` in OCaml 4.02, strings were mutable. Now, strings are intended to be immutable, and `bytes` is the type to be used for "mutable strings".

In order not to break too much existing code, this distinction is not yet enabled by default. In default mode, `bytes` and `string` are synonymous.

Comment: You post sounds like one really needs to enable this mode. That's not true. Everything other this recommendation is written well. Consider removing this misleading recommendation.

Comment: I think that @ivg is right in the sense that your first sentence is awkwardly worded, I would have written it as "in order to achieve this behaviour, string mode must be explicitly enabled"

Comment: should this be updated today? Is it enabled by default now?

Answer (score 11):

There is a slow pace movement in OCaml from mutable string to immutable. A new name for mutable string is `bytes`. The immutable will be still called `string`. As  at the time of writing `bytes` and `string` are just synonyms, so whenever you see `bytes` you may read it as `string`. Moreover, if you update you core version to 112.35.00 or later, you will not see this issue with `bytes`. String will became string again.

Answer (score 8):

As @ivg said, there is a slow movement in OCaml to make the `string` type immutable, and the `bytes` type is going to replace the current `string` type, since it's always useful to have mutable strings in addition to immutable ones.

As of version 4.02.2, there are separate modules for working with the types `string` and `bytes` (`String` and `Bytes`, respectively), but they both just use `bytes` by default.

Byte strings may be modified either with `Bytes.set` or with the `<-` operator, although the latter method will throw a warning. Example:

```
# let byte_string = "dolphins";;
val byte_string : bytes = "dolphins"
# byte_string.[0] <- 'w';;
Characters 0-15:
Warning 3: deprecated: String.set
Use Bytes.set instead.
Characters 0-15:
Warning 3: deprecated: String.set
Use Bytes.set instead.
- : unit = ()
# byte_string;;
- : bytes = "wolphins"
```

Of course, more normal behaviour may be achieved by running OCaml with the `-safe-string` directive, as @rafix said.