# Ocaml concatenating two strings so that a ^ b = b ^ a

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I found a question in a textbook that does not provide an answer.

"Find two non empty strings a and b so that a ^ b = b ^ a.
What could generally be said about a pair of those commuted strings?"

The only strings I could think of is if both a and b is the same, like "aaa" or "apa".
Is the answer this easy or is it more complicated?

And what is the type of ( ^ ) ? if I just enter ( ^ ) in utop I get "bytes -> bytes -> bytes = " but I am gussing the type have to be String ?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500560/why-is-my-string-of-type-bytes

Comment: and what about  `a = "nk"` and `b = "nknk"`?

Comment: yes, ofcourse I did miss that. So could yo say that they have to be the same or one of the strings needs to be made up of  one or more repetitions of the other ?

Comment: @Burton I suppose so

Comment: Ok, last question. The type of ( ^ ), is that String? I read the link that I got in the first comment and from what I could understand the type should be string.

Comment: @Burton yep, it should be `string -> string -> string = <fun>`. I can't explain it better than the guys from the link.

Comment: how about "aa" and "aaa"? None is a repetition of the other.

Answer (score 6):

This holds iff they're repetitions of the same string. See [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80733/cases-where-string-concatenation-is-commutative) for more info.